# How to populate UI from @form content

Tags: html, forms, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I am new to LiveView, Phoenix and Elixir, and I am struggling to populate the UI from the form content.
Here's a simplified version of what I have in my code:
I have defined a struct with some simple fields:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyStruct do
  defstruct some_integer: 3,
            some_string: "",
            some_bool: true
end
```

Then I have a context:

```
defmodule MyApp.Context do
  alias MyApp.MyStruct

  def current_struct() do
    %MyStruct{}
  end
end
```

It simply returns the newly created struct with default values. I will implement modifying later.
Now, I need to display a form populated with these values + allow modifying them.
This is my `_live.ex` file:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.ViewLive do
  alias MyApp.MyStruct
  use MyAppWeb, :live_view

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    {:ok, assign(socket, form: to_form(Map.from_struct(Context.current_struct())))}
  end

  # Here I have handle_event methods, but they don't do anything at the moment.
end
```

Finally, this is the `.heex` file:

```
<div class="container mx-auto my-4">
  <.form for={@form} phx-change="change_form" phx-submit="submit_form">
    <!-- Number picker -->
    <div class="mb-4">
      <.label>I want to pick a number here:</.label>
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 mb-4">
      <label class="cursor-pointer">
    <input type="radio" name="some_integer" value="3" class="hidden" checked={Context.current_struct().some_integer == 3}
    />
        <span class={"px-4 py-2 rounded-md #{if Context.current_struct().some_integer == 3, do: "bg-gray-400", else: "bg-gray-200"} hover:bg-gray-400"}>
          3 of something
        </span>
      </label>
      <!-- More of these integer options -->

    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="mb-4">
      <.input
        label="I'd like this to be true or false:"
        type="checkbox"
        value={Context.current_struct().some_bool}
        field={@form[:some_bool]}
      />
    </div>

    <.button>Submit</.button>
  </.form>
</div>
```

The code above kind of works now for initial values, but it stops working when I select 7 or 10 instead of 3.
Note how to get the value or compute background colours I use `Context.my_struct()` for calculations.
I assume, that if I implement `handle_event("change_form"...)` and modify my `current_struct()` on each change, then the change would also be applied on UI. But I would like to modify the actual struct only on submit, and in the meantime to get the data from the `@form`.
I tried to do that, but failed.

When I try to do something like

```
value={@form[:some_bool]}
```

then it crashes. When I try to use `input_value()`, then I always get nil, even if `inspect(form)` shows that both `some_integer` and `some_bool` have the values that I expect them to have.

Please advise me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume, that if I implement handle_event("change_form"...) and
> modify my current_struct() on each change, then the change would also
> be applied on UI. But I would like to modify the actual struct only on
> submit, and in the meantime to get the data from the @form

In `mount()`, you can extract the values from your struct and store the values in the socket, leaving the struct unchanged, then those values can be used to populate the form in `render()`.  After the user changes something in the form, `handle_event()` will be called, and `handle_event()` will receive the values that were entered into the form *as the second argument*.

In addition, inside `mount()` you can save your original struct in the socket, then in `handle_event()` you will be able to access any values from the struct that you need.  After the user hits Submit, `handle_event()` will receive the final values entered into the form, which you can use to update the original struct.

Here is an example:

```
#==========Your struct code ============

defmodule MyApp.MyStruct do
  defstruct some_integer: 3,
            some_string: "",
            some_bool: true
end

defmodule MyApp.Context do
  alias MyApp.MyStruct

  def current_struct() do
    %MyStruct{}
  end
end

#=======================

defmodule DemoWeb.DemoLive do
  use DemoWeb, :live_view

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    orig_struct = MyApp.Context.current_struct()
    o_int = orig_struct.some_integer
    o_string = orig_struct.some_string
    o_bool = orig_struct.some_bool

    form_data = %{
      "input_int" => o_int,
      "input_string" => o_string,
      "input_bool" => o_bool
    }

    socket = assign(socket,
        my_struct: orig_struct,
        current_int: o_int,
        current_string: o_string,
        current_bool: o_bool,
        my_form: to_form(form_data)
      )

    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def render(assigns) do

    # When you write:
    #
    # <.form for={@my_form} ... >
    #   <.input  field={@my_form[:input_int] } ... />
    #
    # that creates an input element with the type atribute set to "text",
    # the name and id attributes set to "input_int", and the value
    # attribute set to the value corresponding to the "input_int" key in the form data
    # given to to_form().  If there's no key for "input_int" in the form data, then there
    # won't be a value attribute--unless you explicitly set the value attribute.  Explicitly
    # setting the value attribute takes precedence over any form data given to to_form().
    #
    ~H"""
    <div>
      <%= "current integer: #{@current_int}, current string: #{@current_string},
           current bool: #{@current_bool}"  %>
    </div>
    <div>
    <%= "original integer: #{@my_struct.some_integer}, original string: #{@my_struct.some_string},
           original bool: #{@my_struct.some_bool}"  %>
    </div>
    <div>-------</div>
    <div>-------</div>


    <.form for={@my_form} phx-change="changed" phx-submit="save">
      <.input label="Some integer:"
              field={@my_form[:input_int] }
              value={@current_int}

      />
      <.input label="Some string:"
              field={@my_form[:input_string]}
              value={@current_string}
      />
      <.input label="Some bool:"
              field={@my_form[:input_bool]}
              value={@current_bool}
      />
      <.button>Submit</.button>
    </.form>
    """
  end

  def handle_event("changed",
                   %{"input_int" => entered_int,
                     "input_string" => entered_string,
                     "input_bool" => entered_bool
                    },
                  socket) do

    #Do something with entered_int, entered_string, entered_bool, e.g. change
    #the values that the <div> uses:
    socket = assign(socket,
                    current_int: entered_int,
                    current_string: entered_string,
                    current_bool: entered_bool
              )

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_event("save",
                   %{"input_int" => entered_int,
                     "input_string" => entered_string,
                     "input_bool" => entered_bool
                    },
                   socket) do

    start_struct = socket.assigns.my_struct
    updated_struct = %{start_struct | some_integer: entered_int,
                                      some_string: entered_string,
                                      some_bool: entered_bool}
    #Do something with updated_struct, e.g.:
    IO.inspect(updated_struct, label: "[ME]updated struct")

    {:noreply, socket}
  end


end
```

Here is what the LiveView page looks like:

---

[image]

This function definition:

```
 def handle_event("save",
                   %{"input_int" => entered_int,
                     "input_string" => entered_string,
                     "input_bool" => entered_bool
                    },
                   socket) do
```

*pattern matches* on the second argument to extract the values entered into the form.  Pattern matching a map works like this:

```
iex(2)> function_argument = %{"a" => 10, "b" => 20}
%{"a" => 10, "b" => 20}

iex(3)> %{"a" => a_val} = function_argument
%{"a" => 10, "b" => 20}

iex(4)> a_val
10

iex(5)> %{"b" => b_val, "a" => a_val} = function_argument
%{"a" => 10, "b" => 20}

iex(6)> b_val
20

iex(7)> a_val
10
```

You could also do the pattern match like this:

```
 def handle_event("save", payload, socket) do

   %{"input_int" => entered_int,
     "input_string" => entered_string,
     "input_bool" => entered_bool} = payload
```

This code:

```
updated_struct = %{start_struct | some_integer: entered_int,
                                  some_string: entered_string,
                                  some_bool: entered_bool}
```

uses a [special syntax for updating a map or struct](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.3/Map.html) (which looks like the syntax used for lists).  The special syntax ensures that the keys are already in the map so that mispellings don't add new keys to a map.

On the web page, watch the values above the form change as you type in the input fields.  Then hit Submit and examine the output in the terminal window.

> When I try to use input_value(), then I always get nil, even if
> inspect(form) shows that both some_integer and some_bool have the
> values that I expect them to have.

The only way I can get `nil` when I call:

```
Phoenix.HTML.Form.input_value(my_form, :input_int)
```

is if the key does not exist in `my_form`, e.g.:

```
Phoenix.HTML.Form.input_value(my_form, :non_exist)
```

For instance, I can add the following code to the "save" `handle_event()` function:

```
my_form = socket.assigns.my_form
IO.inspect(my_form, label: "[ME]my_form")
IO.inspect(Phoenix.HTML.Form.input_value(my_form, :input_int), label: "[ME]input_value()" )
```

then when I hit Submit, I see the following output in the terminal window:

```
[ME]my_form: %Phoenix.HTML.Form{
  source: %{"input_bool" => true, "input_int" => 3, "input_string" => ""},
  impl: Phoenix.HTML.FormData.Map,
  id: nil,
  name: nil,
  data: %{},
  hidden: [],
  params: %{"input_bool" => true, "input_int" => 3, "input_string" => ""},
  errors: [],
  options: [],
  index: nil,
  action: nil
}
[ME]input_value(): 3
```

Notice that the value returned was the value which was used to create the form in `mount()`.

> When I try to do something like
>
> ```
> value={@form[:some_bool]}
> ```
>
> then it crashes

When I try writing:

```
<.input label="Some integer:"
        field={@my_form[:input_int] }
        value={@my_form[:input_int] } />
```

it crashes for me too:

> Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %Phoenix.HTML.FormField

====

I just read the following in the docs ([Form Bindings](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/form-bindings.html#form-events))

> **Form Events**
> To handle form changes and submissions, use the phx-change
> and phx-submit events. *In general, it is preferred to handle input
> changes at the form level* ....
>
> ```
> def handle_event("validate", %{"user" => params}, socket) do
>   form =
>     %User{}
>     |> Accounts.change_user(params)
>     |> Map.put(:action, :insert)
>     |> to_form()
>
>   {:noreply, assign(socket, form: form)}
> end
> ```

I think that is saying that instead of dynamically changing the value attribute of an input element, you should use the entered values in the form to create a new form with `to_form()`, then assign the new form to the socket.  Like this:

```
...
...
<.form for={@my_form} phx-change="changed" phx-submit="save">
  <.input label="Some integer:"
          field={@my_form[:input_int] }  
                <======= No value attribute
  />
  <.input label="Some string:"
          field={@my_form[:input_string]}
                <======== No value attribute
  />
  <.input label="Some bool:"
          field={@my_form[:input_bool]}
                <======== No value attribute
  />
  <.button>Submit</.button>
</.form>
```

---

```
def handle_event("changed",
                   payload =
                   %{"input_int" => entered_int,
                     "input_string" => entered_string,
                     "input_bool" => entered_bool
                    },
                  socket) do

    #Do something with entered_int, entered_string, entered_bool, e.g. change
    #the values that the <div> uses:
    socket = assign(socket,
                    current_int: entered_int,
                    current_string: entered_string,
                    current_bool: entered_bool,
                    my_form: to_form(payload)   <======== 
              )

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```